# Sparse matrix vector multiplication using MKL DIA routine

Tags: c, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl, diagonal

I am using the MKL library to perform the sparse matrix vector multiplication using diagonal format, When I use the MKL mkl_sdiagemv function I get a "MKL ERROR: Parameter 4 was incorrect on entry to MKL_SDIAGEMV.
" error.

Comment: The link to the documentation is https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468542

Answer (score 1):

Please, see below a basic example illustrating use of several MKL sparse matrix-vector product routines.

```
enter code #include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl_spblas.h"
#include "mkl_types.h"

#define NJOB 6
#define NZMAX 8
#define INFO 0
#define NNZ 8
#define N 4
#define M 4

#define NMETHODS 3

int main()
{
double  Acoo[NZMAX] = {5.0, 8.0, 9.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 1.0, 4.0};
int AJ[NZMAX] ;
int  AI[M+1];
int  ir[NZMAX] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4};
int  jc[NZMAX] = {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4};  
double   Acsr[NZMAX] ;
int  n=N, info=INFO, nnz = NNZ;

int i, j;
int job[NJOB]={2,1,1,0,NZMAX,0};
int job1[NJOB]={0,1,1,0,0,10};

double Adia[N][N];
int ndiag = N;
int idiag = N;
int distance[N];

double *Acsr_rem=NULL;
int *AJ_rem=NULL;
int *AI_rem=NULL;

double v[N]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
double answer[NMETHODS][N];
int lval;
char transa = 'N';

mkl_dcsrcoo (job, &n, Acsr, AJ, AI, &nnz, Acoo, ir, jc, &info);
mkl_dcsrdia (job1, &n, Acsr, AJ, AI,  *Adia,  &ndiag, distance, &idiag, Acsr_rem,   AJ_rem, AI_rem, &info); 
mkl_ddiagemv (&transa, &n, *Adia, &ndiag, distance, &ndiag, v, answer[0]);
mkl_dcoogemv(&transa, &n, Acoo, ir, jc, &nnz, v, answer[1]);
mkl_dcsrgemv(&transa, &n, Acsr, AI, AJ,  v, answer[2]); 

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already figured out how to correct my code.

Comment: @The Hiary: You're welcome (:( i'll not get my bounty :) ). There're a couple of small issues with my code, i'll adjust it a bit later

Comment: No, everything is fine, just removed irrelevant printf's.